# Can I use define specifying a type

Tags: c

Let assume that I can not have a private `typedef` in my header file. So I need to do connection to type that is specified from the outside. In other words the type `MY_INT` should be determined by the interface.

So are these two approaches equal?

### First approach:

In **file.h**

```
#define MY_INT int
```

In **file.c**

```
typedef MY_INT my_int;
my_int *a,b;
```

### Second approach

In **file.c**

```
typedef int my_int; 
my_int *a,b;
```

Do both declare two variables: a pointer to an int and an integer variable?

Comment: Yes, both are the same, `MY_INT` is replaced by `int` in the first case.

Comment: Yes, The first approach looks from my side more readable, because it does show that `MY_INT` is the original type in question.

Comment: This actually happens a lot in the C standard library headers. Many times the "type" in the `typedef` is implementation defined and will have been defined by a `#define` earlier to ensure the the `typedef` alias is of the proper type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do both declare two variables: a pointer to an int and an integer variable?**

Short: yes.

Long:

Macro substitution is nothing else then plain text substitution. So when you `#define MY_INT int`, everything the preprocessor does when he finds a `MY_INT` is replacing it with `int`.

After the preprocessor processed **file.c** in your first approach it will look exactly the same as **file.c** in the second approach.

You can have a look at the preprocessors output with most compilers. E.g. for GCC the command would look like this `gcc -E -o file.i file.c`. **file.i** will then contain the preprocessors output so the actual file wich will be passed to the compiler.

---

This is what GCC produced for your first approach:

```
# 1 "file1.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "file1.c"
# 1 "file.h" 1
# 2 "file1.c" 2

typedef int my_int;

my_int *a, b;
```

and here is the second one

```
# 1 "file2.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "file2.c"
# 1 "file.h" 1
# 2 "file2.c" 2

typedef int my_int;

my_int *a, b;
```

The only thing that differes is the name of the files I used. The rest is exactly the same.

Comment: I thought so as well, but I need to be sure.